# Jackson @XmlRootElement missing from JSON on some environments

Tags: java, json, jboss, jaxb, jackson

I am utilizing Jackson, RESTEasy, Spring and running on a JBOSS server.
I have a standard POJO with JAXB annotations such as the following:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="aRoot")
    public class aRoot{
        @XmlElement
        String aString;
        @XmlElement
        String bString;
    }
```

The issue that I am encountering is that on one server I receive the JSON output of:

```
    {"aRoot":{"aString":"aValue","bString":"bValue"}}
```

Yet on another server I receive the JSON output of:

```
    {"aString":"aValue","bString":"bValue"}
```

I am baffled as to what is going on.  I have the same code deployed on both servers and I believe the two are configured the same way.  However, at this point I'm suck wondering if there is some configuration that needs to be set on the JBOSS server to ensure the root element is processed properly, or if there is something else going on.  Does anyone know why I would be seeing these two distinctly different behaviors across my different environments?

UPDATE:
I resolved the problem.  I managed to do it by creating a class that implements:

```
    ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
```

Then in the constructor I set:

```
    this.objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

And did other required implementation details for a ContextResolver.  I also configured spring to instantiate it as a bean and Jackson picked it up on its own.

Comment: Could be a class path issue since, if I'm not mistaken, Spring discovers Jackson modules via the Java SPI. Check that the Jackson JAXB module is in the class path for both environments.

Comment: Jackson was in the class path in both environments.  I ended up resolving the issue by creating a class that implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> and set this.objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);